# M1.9x How can I reset 1 multiselect attribute for *all* products

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, product-attribute, massaction

I want to reset 1 multiselect attribute for all products.

So remove any value (set to null) for all products and save

Ideally targetting the products that have a value set ... it makes no sense to unset data that is not set

So the logic would be
- find all products with at least some data set for 1 multiselect attribute
- unset the data
- save

question: how can this be done?

thanks

Comment: Did the proposed solution https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/262522/76597 worked for you? Feedback would be nice :-)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to delete the data from the database. With that approach you don't need to find products, load and save them.

Multiselect attributes usually have the `backend_type = varchar`. You can check that for your attribute by running the SQL statement:

```
select * from eav_attribute where attribute_code = '[YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_CODE]';
```

If it is a varchar attribute you can delete all values of this attribute for all products by running the following statement:

```
delete v from catalog_product_entity_varchar v
join  catalog_product_entity p 
  on p.entity_id = v.entity_id
join eav_attribute a 
     on v.attribute_id = a.attribute_id and a.attribute_code = '[YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_CODE]';
```

If you want to test the statement for a single product first you can simply add `where p.sku = '[YOUR SKU]` to the statement and it will delete only the values for that product.

I hope that helps.